# Brutal force for install R version 3.5.2 in VM in Debian GNU/Linux 9

Tags: r, debian, virtual-machine, debian-based

I have a virtual machine of Google Cloud with OS:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

When I try to install R version 3.5.2 doesn't work, always I have `R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"`. But, if I try to make:

```
    sudo apt purge r-base* r-recommended r-cran-*
    sudo apt autoremove
    sudo apt update
    sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/'
deb <favourite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
    apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

Output was:

```
foresteyebrazil@cluster-652f-w-1:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                      
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease                                                        
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease                                                    
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                                
Hit:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-wheezy InRelease                                  
Hit:7 http://storage.googleapis.com/dataproc-bigtop-repo/1_3_deb9_20190426_012600-RC01 dataproc InRelease         
Hit:8 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian stretch InRelease                                        
Hit:9 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-stretch InRelease                              
Hit:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease                                           
Ign:11 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu stretch/ InRelease                             
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu eoan InRelease      
Hit:13 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease
Hit:14 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease               
Err:15 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu stretch/ Release                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.84.239.73 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu eoan Release                                  
  404  Not Found
0% [Working]
```

Here stop to working. Any ideas please? Thanks

Comment: I thought r-base-dev needed to be in there? I don't see a wheezy sub-directory at http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu

Comment: You seem to have (temporary?) issues with IP 99.84.239.73 -- an Amazon domain.  Try commenting out the entry that caused, proceed, and later add it again.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Do you have guidance for where one might find the files that need to be modified? And can you comment on whether you presumed that the OP had done a substitution for "<favourite-cran-mirror>"?

Comment: The entries are generally in files below `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` or in the main `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  That is fairly well documented.